# VBA HTTP request to API with JSON body returns empty array (MSXML2.XMLHTTP in Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, api, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

**Update: SOLVED** --> Look below for answer.

**Update:**
At the Microsoft docs i can see that when open method is called with Async=false, the response might not return if "the protocol stack times out", however I have not been able to read up on the timeout timers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms931177%28v%3dmsdn.10%29
Not really sure if it's related or not.

I'm trying to retrieve a JSON response object through VersionOne query API.
When i try to read the responseText in VBA I receive an empty array, however the exact same request returns correct data from PostMan. I get an HTTP 200 code response, but no data in the response body.

The reason for doing it in VBA and Excel is that the data needs to be analalyzed in a pre-existing Excel model.
I've tried different auth possibilities, both OAUTH and Basic.

**This is the VBA code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test_LateBinding()

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim body As String
    Dim strResponseHeaders As String
    Dim allResponseHeader As String

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    strUrl = "https://endpoint"
    body = " { ""from"": ""Epic"",""select"": []}"    
    'with basic'
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False, "XXXX", "XXXX"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send body
        strResponseHeaders = .StatusText
        strResponse = .ResponseText
        allResponseHeader = .GetAllResponseHeaders
    End With
    Debug.Print body
    Debug.Print allResponseHeader
    Debug.Print strResponse

End Sub
```

**This is my console output:**

```
OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
V1-MemberID: skatteministeriet/120267
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
VersionOne: Ultimate/19.0.3.29; 0
X-Instart-Request-ID: 3912039762705832388:SEN01-NPPRY25:1553377406:0

[]
```

**This is the PostMan response headers**:
[PostMan response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88XYh.png)

**This is the URL and request JSON body:**
[URL and request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PtrV.png)

Comment: No, it's supposed to be a get request. :)

Comment: Can you point to which example in the guidance aligns with your use case? The closest I found so far is a POST request here: https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Sample_Code/Query_for_progress_on_an_epic

Comment: Endpoint introduction
https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Getting_Started/Platform_Concepts/Endpoints/query.v1

Endpoint tour
https://community.versionone.com/VersionOne_Connect/Developer_Library/Sample_Code/Tour_of_query.v1

Tbh the documentation is horribly organized, it's structured so wierd...

Comment: Could you please provide a valid URL? Also, add a screenshot of the working OK PostMan request with all headers and parameters to the question (or the link).

Comment: The valid URL for the endpoint will be troublesome to post, since the endpoint is organisation independant and therefore "non-disclosable". However, screenshots of the PostMan request i s possible. I will update this post with it.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED** Finally...

So i found the answer.
After re-analyzing the Postman response i found that the JSON response was actually handed as a gzip encoded response. Which is simply not compatible with the MSXML2.XMLHTTP lib.

So to solve the problem all I did was to use the WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 lib instead, which is basicly newer. No other changes to the code was needed.

So to others out there using MSXML2.XMLHTTP or the WinHTTPserver.6.0 lib, change to the newer library :)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Test_LateBinding()

    Dim objRequest As Object
    Dim strUrl As String
    Dim strResponse As String
    Dim body As String
    Dim strResponseHeaders As String
    Dim allResponseHeader As String

    Set objRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    strUrl = "https://endpoint"
    body = " { ""from"": ""Epic"",""select"": []}"    
    'with basic'
    With objRequest
        .Open "GET", strUrl, False, "XXXX", "XXXX"
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        .Send body
        strResponseHeaders = .StatusText
        strResponse = .ResponseText
        allResponseHeader = .GetAllResponseHeaders
    End With
    Debug.Print body
    Debug.Print allResponseHeader
    Debug.Print strResponse

End Sub
```